# greasemonkey script for gmail

Tags: button, gmail, position, greasemonkey

I am completely new to script writing. I have to write a script in which I need to add a button next to the send button on the Gmail page.
I made the button in a div, so that it is now added to the interface, but I can't seem to position it in the right place. Any tips?

Comment: actually, i can move the div around, but it then overlaps the other interface elements and covers them up. i want that the new button becomes a part of the same div in which the Send button lies, and no overlapping occurs. Please help!!!

Answer (score 1):

You're probably adding the button onto Gmail's top frame. Gmail uses multiple frames in their interface; the frame that contains the actual UI we all see (except for the chat boxes) is the "canvas_frame".

Put in a check to make sure that the script is operating on the correct frame. For example, in [a Gmail script I wrote](http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/104846), I checked for the 'cP' class element (the body's class is cP).

```
if (document.getElementsByClassName('cP')[0]) {
    // You know that you're in the canvas_frame because the outer frame does not contain any elements with the classname 'cP'
    // Put all your code here
}
```

Hope this helps!